# Find the conditional probability density function given an event

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to approach this question:

---

The probability density function (PDF) of a continuous random variable $X$ is given by

$$f_X\left(x\right)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\left(2x+3\right)}{4} & \text{0 $\leq$ x $\leq$ 1,} \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

Find the conditional PDF of $X$ given event $A = \{0.6 < X < 1.2\}$, $f_{X}\left(x \mid A\right)$.

---

Using the formula

$$f_{A}\left(x \mid A\right) = \frac{d}{dx} F_X \left(x \mid A \right)$$

and

$$F_X \left(x \mid A \right)=\frac{P\left[\{X \le x\} \cap A\right]}{P\left[A\right]}$$

I determined $F_X \left(x\right)$ as

$$F_X\left(x\right)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{$x < 0$,} \\
\frac{x^2 + 3x}{4} & \text{$0 \le x \le 1$,} \\
1 & x>1
\end{cases}$$

but this is where I got stuck. I'm not sure how to incorporate the given restrictions of $A$ and the restrinctions of $F_X \left(x\right)$ at the same time to get the full piecewise equation for $F_{X}\left(x \mid A\right)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don’t want the CDF $P[X\leq x]$. You want $P[\{X\leq x\} \cap A]$. Compute this for different regions of $x$. For example it is 0 when $x<.6$.

Comment: @Michael I think I understand how to get $0$ for when $x < 0.6$, but I still don't quite understand what to do for when $0.6 \le x \le 1.2$, as I'm not too sure if I should split it according to the restrictions of the CDF (i.e. $0.6 \le x \le 1.0$ and $1.0 < x \le 1.2$) or just use the restriction $0.6 \le x \le 1.2$ as is.

Comment: The first one. It does not hurt to consider many cases.